# Dynamic way to hide divs using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, object

Is there a more dynamic way to hide/show divs that are identical in structure with no identifiers?

```
<div class="setup" onclick="show(0)">
Click to show
  <p class="hidden">
    I'm some stuff
  </p>
</div>

<div class="setup" onclick="show(1)">
Click to show
  <p class="hidden">
    I'm more stuff
  </p>
</div>


function show(elem) {   
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
  if (p[elem] != undefined) {
    if (p[elem].style.display == "none") {
        p[elem].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      p[elem].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ba7yfmz6/29/

Comment: Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/205xgz4w/ for a little code review

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `this`:

```
<div class="setup" onclick="show(this)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function show(elem) {
    var paragraph = elem.querySelector(".hidden");
    if (paragraph.style.display == "none") {
        paragraph.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        paragraph.style.display = "none";
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @froggomad Please note that this will get you in trouble when you are dealing with non-block elements. I personally would toogle a class "hidden", and define how the specific element should be hidden in css.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way!

You can get all your elements, iterate them via `forEach` and assign your function to their `onclick` property:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.setup').forEach(div => {
    div.onclick = showElem;
});
```

Doing this, you can get rid of the `onlick` on your HTML elements.

---

To get their child element (the one you want to hide / show, obviously), your `show()` function can look like this:

```
function show() {
    const hidden = this.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0];
    if (hidden.style.display == 'none') {
    hidden.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    hidden.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

And all together:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.setup').forEach(div => {
 div.onclick = show;
});

function show() {
 const hidden = this.getElementsByClassName('hidden')[0];
 if (hidden.style.display == 'none') {
   hidden.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
   hidden.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.setup {
  border-top: solid #ccc 3px;
  border-bottom: solid #ccc 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.setup:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: solid black 3px;
  border-bottom: solid black 3px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="setup">
Click to show
  <p class="hidden">
    I'm some stuff
  </p>
</div>

<div class="setup">
Click to show
  <p class="hidden">
    I'm more stuff
  </p>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ba7yfmz6/38/

---

More info:

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this`.

Also, since the `div` doesn't have a `style` attribute, checking for `style.display === 'none'` would always be false on the first click; it would set the the `style.display` to none. Checking for the computed style would show the hidden element on first click.

```js
function show(el) {
  const toggle = el.querySelector('.hidden');
  
  toggle.style.display = window.getComputedStyle(toggle).display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

```css
.setup {
  border-top: solid #ccc 3px;
  border-bottom: solid #ccc 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.setup:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-top: solid black 3px;
  border-bottom: solid black 3px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="setup" onclick="show(this)">
Click to show
  <p class="hidden">
    I'm some stuff
  </p>
</div>

<div class="setup" onclick="show(this)">
Click to show
  <p class="hidden">
    I'm more stuff
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="setup" onclick="show(this)">
```

Then the JavaScript:

```
function show(that) {   
    var hiddenElements = that.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
    for (var i = 0; i < hiddenElements.length; i++) {
        var style = hiddenElements[i].style;
        style.display = style.display == "block" ? "none" : "block";
    }
}
```